# ORDER BY not sorting as intended SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I'm having an issue sorting with the ORDER BY clause and was hoping someone could assist me in figuring out why this is not sorting as intended.

I am pulling data points from multiple databases and adding them to a temporary table for output in an SSRS report.  I've also included a WHILE statement to insert NULL values to fill the intended space with empty rows if there are not enough records.

I've changed most of the column names to protect potentially sensitive information, but the column in question is v1 and ob.LineNumber.

```
USE db    GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[db1]
@PR_ID INT

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #temp
(v1 INT,
v2 VARCHAR(50),
v3 VARCHAR(50),
v4 VARCHAR(50),
v5 FLOAT,
v6 FLOAT,
v7 FLOAT,
v8 FLOAT,
v9 VARCHAR(50),
v10 FLOAT,
v11 VARCHAR(50),
v12 VARCHAR(50),
v13 VARCHAR(50),
v14 VARCHAR(50),
v15 FLOAT)

DECLARE @RowCount INT, @h INT
SET @RowCount = 11

INSERT INTO #temp(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15)
SELECT  ob.LineNumber AS v1,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        CASE WHEN ob.Length IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ob.Length END AS v5,
        CASE WHEN ob.Width IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ob.Width END AS v6,
        CASE WHEN ob.Length IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (ob.Length * ob.Width) END AS v7,
        NULL,
        sovg.Grade AS v9,
        ob.AYB As v10,
        ob.CC AS v11,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        ob.PC AS v14,
        ob.VT AS v15

FROM t_ob WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN t_otpr otpr WITH (NOLOCK) ON ob.ID=otpr.ID
    LEFT JOIN t_pr pr WITH (NOLOCK) ON otpr.PR_ID=pr.PR_ID
    LEFT JOIN t_otb otb WITH (NOLOCK) ON ob.ID=otb.ID
    LEFT JOIN t_b b WITH (NOLOCK) ON otb.B_ID=b.B_ID
    LEFT JOIN t_G sovg WITH (NOLOCK) ON ob.G_ID=sovg.G_ID

WHERE       pr.PR_ID = @PR_ID
ORDER BY    ob.LineNumber ASC

SET @h = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp)

WHILE  @h < @RowCount OR @h % @RowCount > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp (v1) VALUES (NULL)
    SET @h = @h + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #temp 

END
```

And my results come up like this:

```
v1
----------
6
2
8
9
5
4
3
7
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the result set from:

```
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Then what you are doing wrong is assuming that the result set is in a particular order.  The *only* way to get a result set in a particular order is to include an explicit `ORDER BY` clause for the outermost `SELECT`.

Comment: And just to expand a little, `ORDER BY` on an `INSERT` is essentially meaningless. SQL Server stores table data in unordered sets. If you need to impose an order, it has to be, as Gordon notes, on your outermost `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a silly mistake I made, but to be fair, it seemed to work on a similar query I was using for a different dataset.  I'll have to modify both queries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `ORDER BY` only happens on the INSERT.

Databases work because of relational set theory. Adhering to that theory is what allows for many of the optimizations and practices that make them both fast to query and safe for simultaneous access. In this context, a database table is a relational set, and *relational sets are not ordered by definition.*

You can insert into the table in any order you want, but that order *does not matter* when it's time to retrieve the data again. To ensure you get a specific order, you *must* declare that order at the time you query the table:

```
SELECT * FROM #temp ORDER BY v1
```

Additionally, the ORDER BY clause at the end of INSERT statement serves no functional purpose and can be removed.

Comment: To add: if the table has an identity column, then my understanding is that using INSERT .. SELECT .. ORDER BY  gives you control over the order in which identity values are assigned.